# Find specific JSON object in JSONArray from HttpResponse

Tags: json, rest, httpclient, response

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
int statuscode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
System.out.println(responseBody);
```

The response i'm getting looks like this as an example:

```
{"developerMessage":"The requested resource is not available.",
"httpStatusCode":"404",
"errors":[{"developerMessage":"Savings account with identifier 15 does not exist"
```

What I want to be getting is " Savings account with identifier 15 does not exist " as a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "    \"developerMessage\": \"The requested resource is not available.\",\n" +
                "    \"httpStatusCode\": \"404\",\n" +
                "    \"errors\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"developerMessage\": \"Savings account with identifier 15 does not exist\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            String string = jsonObject.getString("errors");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string);
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String message = jsonObject2.getString("developerMessage");
            Log.i("YourApp", message);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I get the following error: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["errors"] not a string.

Comment: My code tested OK before I post. I think you should check your response message if it is valid Json. You can check at jsonlint.com. See my jsonString, is it different from your?

Comment: the jsonString you posted, is what i get as output in java when println(responseBody), which i'm getting from String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: I'm not looking to hard-code the error, I want to get the error as a response, and be able to use the error string to INSERT it into my database

Comment: Ok, post your new code that causes org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["errors"] not a string, so that I can check.

Comment: In your question, responseBody value misses some last characters such as ], } to make it a valid Json. Pls check again.

Comment: thanks, alittle late but with more knowledge I understood your answer better and now it works like a charm